# OpenCV/OpenCL on Android shows weird behaviour when imwrite()

Tags: android, opencv, opencl, opencv3.0

I'm trying to read an image, convert it to uMat and process it. I do the same with and without the new T-API in OpenCV 3.0. I was able to build the libraries and the logcats say that OpenCL works. When comparing the output CPU/GPU, it differs. Laplacian in CPU looks as expected, the same "algorithm" in OCL/uMat way is mostly black, only a few features are available. Is this a problem due to memory shifting from GPU to Java?

CPU-Code:

```
ocl::setUseOpenCL(false);
Mat cpuFrame;
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO/";
String filename = "DSC_0581.JPG";
String filename_result = "DSC_0581_cpu_processed.JPG";

Mat cpuBW;
Mat cpuBlur;
Mat cpuEdges;

cpuFrame = imread(path+filename);
startTimer=clock();
cvtColor(cpuFrame, cpuBW, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
GaussianBlur(cpuBW, cpuBlur, Size(1, 1), 1.5, 1.5);
Canny(cpuBlur, cpuEdges, 0, 30, 3);
stopTimer = clock();
imwrite(path+filename_result, cpuEdges);
```

GPU-Code:

```
cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);
    Mat mat = cv::imread(path+filename);
    UMat gpuFrame = mat.getUMat(cv::ACCESS_READ);

    if (mat.empty()) {
        LOGD("Image Empty");
    }
    cvtColor(gpuFrame, gpuBW, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::Laplacian(gpuBW, gpuBW, CV_8U);
    cv:multiply(gpuBW, 10, gpuBW);
    imwrite(path+filename_result+".png", gpuBW, compression_params);
    cv::ocl::finish();

    normalize(gpuBW, gpuBW, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, -1);

    imwrite(path+"resultNormalize.jpg", gpuBW, compression_params);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not an expert but, Are you using UMats in gpuBW ?

Comment: Sorry, for not declaring the gpu*-UMats. When assigning each step in the UMat manipulation with a new UMat the result is better. But the computation time has increased by far. Another question. My device is a Xperia Z1 which has an Adreno 330 GPU. It should work with KitKat and OCL 1.1. Lollipop is the actual firmware now, does this cause any issues? I'm not very familiar with OpenCL with Android though..Thank you!